# A list of all units versus each unit in Starcraft 2

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a list, where I can look exactly, in which order the units of one race are good against a specific unit?

**For example:** I scouted and see *"He is coming in with a bunch of Zealots"*. I play Zerg and have some different units already built, but I don't know which of them are best against Zealots.

Now I need a ranking of all Zerg units, in which order they are good against Zealots

Comment: This is a very broad topic, (as there tends to be multiple specific scenarios for each unit and army composition) and is likely to be closed as such. Perhaps you could edit this to make it more specific to a particular race, or combo of units? (something like 'What combos can counter an MMM ball?', or 'How to deal with mass Roaches as Protoss?', that sort of thing.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the efficiency of the units vary quite a bit depending on micromanagement skills. For example without micro, banelings handily defeat clumps of marines. However with good marine splitting the efficiency of banelings are diminished. So the answer to the question will vary depending on the skill level of the players.

Comment: If you just want to study which units do well and which units do poorly against which units from other races, check out the help section within SC2 itself.

Comment: As i stated in my answer. This is very blurry, because all units counter eachother. Its just a matter of numbers, positioning and the total composition of units. 2 Marines can kill a banshee. But a Banshee can kill 2 marines. Who was the best positioning, micromanagment and upgrades. The counter list that blizzard has is the obivious counter, and is a great rule of thumb. Another example is a Ghost and a Broodlord, both can kill eatch and are great against eatchother. You should be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closest thing to what you are looking would be [this](http://vaughnroyko.com/sciicounters/).

You can find more similar guides online,but the most common problem is that they are text based meaning it takes a lot of space and time to find what you are looking for(especially while in-game).

Comment: That looks great, but how do I understand the Counter Charts? What does it mean, if there are two or three counter units in the same box? Do I need them together or do they work all alone?

Comment: They work alone,it is up to you to decide what ratio of those units will you make depending on your current units,resources,tactic and micro management capabilities.

Comment: Also note that some units have additional information at the top of their profiles,for example that hey are only soft counters or that you need to have a large group of specific unit.

Comment: [That overview](http://vaughnroyko.com/sciicounters/) is realy useful, but one strange thing: why is there no Ultralistk as counter to Roaches? [Here](http://sea.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit/roach#best) it sais that roaches are weak against Ultralisks

Comment: Well this guide is only partially based on the blizzards guide,the other half is based on the starcraft 2 guide(book) in which author possibly had other reasons for counters...My opinion is that ultralisks are too expensive just to counter lower tier units like roaches,which can be countered by cheaper units which can also be build much sooner.

Answer (score 2):

Blizzard made their own unit guide.
Its pretty good and can be found here: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit/
You can select an individual unit, and see its strong and weak sides.
Try selceting the Zealot and see which Zerg unit has an advantage against it.

To be honest, with skill or "Micromanagement", a unit isnt stronger than the one controling it.

Comment: Sure, that guide is also implemented inside the game, but it only shows **one** counterunit of each race

Comment: @rubo77 They can be considered to be "hard-counters" which means that its the obvious counter for a unit. BUT. All units counter all units, its really just a matter of numbers and positioning of the units. Thats why there no head on answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Depends too much on your micro skills. In some cases zealot sentry can counter roaches without a problem. In most cases the roaches just tear through the units.

There are a couple of known counter types:
-Soft
-Hard
-Universal
-mobility

-Soft counter is for example the stalker to the roach. The stalker has a bit of more range and deals extra bonus damage. When equal supplies of both units clash, the stalkers will win (with significant losses)

-Hard a hard counter is a unit who specializes in destroying units of a specific (armor) type. For example the immortal vs siege tanks, the hellions vs zerglings, collosi vs marines.

-Universal - when the countered unit can't really do much against the counterer. Banshees vs baneligns is a good example here.

-Mobility - Mutalisks versus roach hydra. Although not as viable anymore due to the buff of the spore crawlers, when you can outmaneuver your opponent you can easily go for a base trade and win a lost game. For a lot of months in WoL, pvp was basically, blink stalker(mobility) versus immortal sentry (strong counter, but very immobile) and the match up ended with base races.

Note: Mobility requires control.

So, just think of the ways you can build any of the counter types given your economy, map and when you think he will attack.

Comment: So is there an overview with all possible counters?

Comment: Not really, that is what I was aiming at. There are too many variables to be able to determine in which situation which units will be a better counter. The blizzard made list can give a basic idea of things (since it takes into account the different attack and armor types) but regarding mobility and micro potential there isn't a list of which I know that covers things in depth.